# angular2 call function of parent component

Tags: angular

I have an app where I have an upload component where I can upload a file. It is embedded in the `body.component`.

On upload, it should use a function (e.g. `BodyComponent.thefunction()`) of the parent component (do a call to update the data): but only if it the parent is specifically the `body.component`. The upload might also be used elsewhere with different behavior.

Something like `parent(this).thefunction()`, how to do that?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

I would create a custom event in the child component. Something like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  (...)
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output()
  uploaded = new EventEmitter<string>();

  uploadComplete() {
    this.uploaded.emit('complete');
  }
```

Your parent component could register on this event

```js
@Component({
  template `
    <child-comp (uploaded)="someMethod($event)"></child-comp>
  `,
  directives: [ ChildComponent ]
})
export class ParentComponent {
  (...)

  someMethod(event) {
  }
}
```

Another way would be to inject the parent component in the child one, but they will be strongly linked together...

Comment: Any idea why I have an Output undefined error? It's defined in typescript at the top by importing from `angular2/core`. Console log shows a problem with angular2-polyfills

Comment: Oh there is a typo in my answer: `@Ouput` instead of `@Output`. It could be the problem... I updated my answer.

Comment: Heh, didn't notice. That was it.

Comment: Now getting an `uploadComplete is not defined` Note that I just copied these as examples. The parent has "someMethod" as well, but it already has an issue with `uploadComplete`. The parent component does use the (uploaded) binding on the child node, and it already had the child as a directive.

Comment: Is the `uploadComplete` method defined in the child component? How do you call it?

Comment: Yes, I do not call uploadComplete correctly, I forgot `this`. Afterwards, it turns out you also forgot `this` on `uploaded` call :) Thanks it works now!

Comment: quite useful! this is the first time I try something new in angular and it works at the first attempt :)

Comment: directives and pipes inside @Component is deprecated from angular RC6.

Comment: `directives` does not appear in `@Component` as far as I can tell in Angular 5 :(

Comment: what if i am using router-outlet? Will it still work?

Comment: This is actually a standard way of dealing with child data sent to parent component.

Comment: simply injected is worked well for me.

Answer (score 66):

Below is the code that worked for me in the latest

## **Angular 5+**

```ts
class ChildComponent {
  @Output() myEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  callParent() {
    this.myEvent.emit('eventDesc');
  }
}
```

In `ParentTemplate`'s template

```ts
<child-component (myEvent)="anyParentMethod($event)"
```

Comment: This is a good solution, because its simple, and the parent decides which method to call. Me like :-)

Comment: What if I m using router-outlet? Can i still use (myEvent)?

Comment: Its for child component used inside parent component. Not sure About router-outlet. May be this question helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949476/how-to-call-router-outlet-child-component-method-from-parent-comonent

Answer (score 40):

## Solution without events involved.

Suppose that I have a `ChildComponent` and from that I want to call the method `myMethod()` which belongs to `ParentComponent` (keeping the original parent's context).

#### Parent Component class:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class ParentComponent {

    get myMethodFunc() {
        return this.myMethod.bind(this);
    }

    myMethod() {
         ...
    }
}
```

#### Parent template:

```
<app-child [myMethod]="myMethodFunc"></app-child>
```

#### Child template

```
@Component({ ... })
export class ChildComponent {

    @Input() myMethod: Function;

    // here I can use this.myMethod() and it will call ParentComponent's myMethod()
}
```

Comment: I've tried using this but it does not work for me. In my version of myMethod, it references a tabset on the parent component (I'm trying to switch tabs from a child of the parent). When I reference this in the parent, everything works. From the child it's getting into myMethod, but not changing the tab. So I'm wondering if the tabset it is referencing is a copy of the real one when the child is accessing it. I'm not actually sure what's happening here when `this.myMethod.bind(this)` is being returned. (Possibly I'm instead doing something fundamentally wrong.)

Comment: I know but I am not using the 8th version. I need this for Ionic 3 that uses the 5 version.

Comment: @VasilisGreece I'm not sure how to help you, but I strongly suggest you to update to latest Ionic version (currently 4)

Comment: Simplest and most direct way to call the parent's method avoiding unnecessary imports. Using Angular 10 on 2020-11-13. Appreciated.

Comment: This works on 1-27-2022, I tried a lot of other methods including Output() but they all failed but this worked! Thank you, you're brilliant.

Answer (score 24):

You can inject the parent component to the child component.

For more details see
- [How do I inject a parent component into a child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540615/how-do-i-inject-a-parent-component-into-a-child-component)
- [Angular 2 child component refers to parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691899/angular-2-child-component-refers-to-parent-component)
This way you can ensure that `thefunction()` is only called when parent is a `body.component`.

```ts
constructor(@Host() bodyComp: BodyComponent) {
```

Otherwise using `@Output()` is preferred to communicate from child to parent.

Comment: Btw, I had to do `constructor(@Host() bodyComp: BodyComponent)`.. perhaps it was changed recently. Works great, thx!

Comment: Thanjs a lot, I mixed something up - fixed

Answer (score 3):

In parent html:

```html
<child [parent]="this"></child>
```

In child component:

```js
@Input() parent: ParentComponent;
// then do whatever with `this.parent`
```

Events have their places, but I don't see anything else is simpler than this.

Comment: For Angular 13, this is the only answer that works.