# How to call router outlet child component method from parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am new to angular2

```
<parent>
    <router-outlet><router-outlet>
</parent>
```

I have a button in parent component, if I click that button it should call a method in the child component (which is loaded in router outlet.)

Is there any way to call the child component (in router outlet) method from parent ?

Comment: In your sample code, `<router outlet>` should be `<router-outlet>` with a dash.

Answer (score 13):

There are basically two ways to display a component's template: As a nested component or as a routing target.

**Nested Component**

If you use a nested component, then the components are considered to have a "parent component/child component" relationship.

The Html for the parent component would then look like this:

```
<div>
   <child></child>
</div>
```

Where "child" is the selector of the child component. You can then communicate between the two using @Input and @Output properties.

For more information on this technique when you have **nested** components, check out the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

**Routing Target**

If you use a component as a routing target by displaying it in a `<router-outlet>`, then there is no "parent component" and "child component" relationship.

The best way to communicate between components in this case is to use a service.

I have a blog post about creating a service here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

**Resources**

If you are new to Angular, you may save your self a bunch of time and frustration by working through a tutorial or online course. That will introduce all of the basic concepts to get you on your way with Angular quickly.

You can work through the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial here: https://angular.io/tutorial

Or watch a course such as this one: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update

Or this one: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-first-look/table-of-contents

(You can sign up for a free week.)

Answer (score 13):

With child in `router-outlet`, you can use `ContentChild` to be able to call a method in the child. So...

```
import { ContentChild } from '@angular/core';
```

in your parent:

```
@ContentChild(ChildComponent)
private childComponent: ChildComponent;
```

and on your click event do:

```
this.childComponent.doSomething()
```

Also you need to add your child component in the providers array in parent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  ...
  providers: [ChildComponent]
})
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, ContentChild is pre defined and Childcomponent  is user defined. I tried, but I am getting cannot call methodXXx from undefined

Comment: Aaah, knew I forgot something :P You need to add the child in providers array in parent (no need to inject it in constructor), edited my answer :) It should work now. And you are correct in the assumption you made in the comment.

Comment: One last question,. It is calling child method perfectly.but in child method. I an reassigning a variable. I don't see UI rendering based on new assignment.can you please suggest.

Comment: Well that's not really enough information. Could you fork the plunker I made to showcase the issue?

Comment: I have created , 
plnkr.co/edit/e7HdIv9Mqeky00nHADvJ?p=preview

1st click on load child, then child is loaded in routeroutlet. now click on change name button. i am able to call the method from App component but , in child component the name element is not rendering in router-outlet

Answer (score 6):

I found two ways to achieve this:

**1. Injecting the main component into children**

You can add an event to your main component, inject the main component to your child components and subscribe to the event. See the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/1BvIuO1jpYlRV0oRKy8L?p=preview) that illustrates this. But, now your children have a dependency on your main component. This may be not good.

> main component

```
executeAction: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
constructor() { }
performAction() {
  this.executeAction.emit();
}
```

> child

```
constructor(private appComponent: AppComponent) {
    this.executeAction = this.executeAction.bind(this);
    eventSubscriber(appComponent.executeAction, this.executeAction);
}
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    eventSubscriber(this.appComponent.executeAction, this.executeAction, true);
}
executeAction() {
    alert('1');
}
```

**2. Implementing a service**

The best solution here and as described in [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) is to create a service that will be an additional layer between the main component and children. In this way, you will be independent from the main component implementation. See the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/jym6MIQVMWF93KAobmUp?p=preview) that illustrates this approach.

> service

```
subscription = new Subject();
executeAction() {
    this.subscription.next();
}
```

> main component

```
constructor(private appService: AppService) { }
performAction() {
  this.appService.executeAction();
}
```

> child

```
constructor(private appService: AppService) {
    this.executeAction = this.executeAction.bind(this);
    eventSubscriber(appService.subscription, this.executeAction);
}
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    eventSubscriber(this.appService.subscription, this.executeAction, true);
}
executeAction() {
    alert('1');
}
```

Comment: This worked a treat... thank you so much. My situation was a dialog being opened in a parent component that directly changed the child (via router-outlet) component but service object wasn't being reflected correctly in child component. Not sure how expensive this is on resources though?

Comment: what is "eventSubscriber" here? I am getting error on same " cannot find name eventSubscriber "

Answer (score 5):

I think [Event emitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) can do the trick for you

Though you can use it directly in child component also but using a common service here would be a good practice

First you need to create an emitter in a service something like

```
export class EmitterService {
   public nameEmitter:EventEmitter<string>=new EventEmitter(); 

    //method to get question
    changeName(name:string){   
        this.nameEmitter.emit(name)    
    }

}
```

Then in root component inject service dependency and call change name method to emit the change

```
 constructor(private emitter :EmitterService) {}
 this.emitter.changeName("New Name");
```

And at the end in child component subscribe to changes

```
this.emitter.nameEmitter.subscribe(name=>{this.name=name})
```

Here is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d42bKafINUqJ1xDQKpXo?p=preview)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [**shared service**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) to communicate with components added by the router.

You can also use the [**activate event**](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#members) of the Router outlet for the parent to know when a component was added by the router

**Template**

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

**Component**

```
  onActivate(componentRef){
    componentRef.works();
  }
```

**Child Comp**

```
 works(){
    console.log("works");
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by the following way as well:

.html

```
<parent>
    <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"><router-outlet>
</parent>
```

.ts

```
activatedComponentReference:any

onActivate(activatedComponentReference) {
  this.activatedComponentReference = activatedComponentReference;
}

onBtnClick() {
   const childRouteComp = this.activatedComponentReference as ChildRouteComponent;
   childRouteComp.childFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to call router outlet child component method from the parent component.

1. ViewChild/ViewChildren - You can use ViewChild/ViewChildren to get the element(s) or the directive(s) matching the selector from the view DOM. It doesn't matter child component is rendered by router outlet.

   import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
   @ViewChild(HomeComponent)
   private childComponent: HomeComponent;

Then you can call any method,

```
this.childComponent.changeTitle();
```

[Demo - call router outlet child component method](https://codepen.io/MarkiE/pen/oGwXrJ)

2. Shared services - Since angular services are singleton by injecting them to your controllers you can call methods. (Above answers are already mentioned this approach)

Answer (score 0):

After i searched a lot about this issue, i found a solution and wish it could help you.
contentChild/ViewChild have no access to component(and it's data) that is loaded in router-outlet, and using sharedService needs an extra file and more code.

You just need to read component that is loaded in the router outlet:

1. Add template reference to your router outlet:

   ```
   <router-outlet #myRouterOutlet ></router-outlet>
   ```
2. Import the RouterOutlet from @angular/router :

   ```
   import {...
      RouterOutlet,
      ..} from "@angular/router";
   ```
3. And finally, use it:

   ```
   @ViewChild("myRouterOutlet", { static: true }) routerOutlet: RouterOutlet;
   buttonClicked(){
       const childComp = this.routerOutlet.component as childComponent;
       childComp.childFunction();
   }
   ```

Hope it could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Although it is an old questions, all the replies here are not perfect.

By using either service or child instance, you bind yourself to a specific function
name that you need to call. service also forces you to use dependency injection.

There is a better way, by using a directive which makes each side completely independent
from the other.

the directive is [ng-router-outlet-comm](https://github.com/zohar1000/ng-router-outlet-comm).

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solution worked for me in Angular 10. Let me share with you CustomEventHandler service I created to manage this problem:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomEventHandler {

    private eventHandlersMap: Map<string, Function> = new Map();

    constructor() {
    }

    public callEvent(eventName: string, data?: any): void {
        this.eventHandlersMap.get(eventName)(data);
    }

    public addListener(eventName: string, callback: Function): void {
        this.eventHandlersMap.set(eventName, callback);
    }
}
```

You can addListener in child component constructor and call any method in component from parent.

```
// add listener in child component
this.customEventHandler.addListener("some-event", this.someMethodToCall.bind(this));
// call this in parent component
this.customEventHandler.callEvent("some-event");
```