# Get access to child route :id

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a child component and its parent component. The child component contains the following pipe to subscribe to the activated route:

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  map(paramMap => +paramMap.get('id')),
  switchMap((id: number) => this.apiService.getTasks(id.toString())),
).subscribe(tasks => this.tasks = tasks);

{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '0', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '0', component: NoListComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: ListComponent }
    ]},
```

How can I get access to this route :id inside of the parent component `DashboardComponent`?

I'm asking because I need to work with the same id inside of the parent. I've already tried to pass it via `@ViewChild` but this won't update on route change.

**EDIT: Event Emitting is not possible since I'm using router outlet.**

Comment: You can emmit the value to the parent component, see here https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter and here at the docs https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass values from child to parent component in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228423/how-to-pass-values-from-child-to-parent-component-in-angular-4)

Comment: @Harry But how where do I put (property)="customFunction", when I have a router-outlet?

Comment: maybe a stackblitz could help us to understand your problem

Comment: ActivatedRoute has a `children` property. Maybe if you combine that with `router.event` and listen for the `ChildActivationStart` or `ChildActivationEnd` property you can get the params?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call router outlet child component method from parent comonent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949476/how-to-call-router-outlet-child-component-method-from-parent-comonent)

Answer (score 0):

Parent-Child component communication over the router-outlet is achieved by modifying the onActivate function of the Parent component, like so:

```
onActivate(childComponent) {
    childComponent.someEventEmitter.subscribe((data) => {
    // Will receive the data from child here 
})
```

The Child component creates the EventEmitter as per usual:

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output() someEventEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  someFunction(data) {
    // emit data to parent component
    this.someEventEmitter.emit(data);
  }
}
```

And in the html:

```
<button type="button" (click)="someFunction()">Do Something</button>
```