# Ionic side menu - trigger function in view.ts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I have a menu in the main `app.component.html`

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
    <ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list no-lines width="10">
          <ion-list-header>
            <h2>MyApp</h2>
          </ion-list-header>  
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="true">
            <ion-item click='MainView.fooBar()'>
              Foo Bar
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
    ....
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

And I allow it open in my main view. The menu is disabled in other views.
Now, how do I trigger a click event in my menu that would call a specific method like above

```
class MainView implements OnInit {
 fooBar(){}
}
```

Through the router object somehow? I do not understand because `MainView` is shown in
`<ion-router-outlet id="main-content">` and the whole is defined in `app.components`.

Comment: I need to trigger an event from the menu that needs to be caught in `MainView` and not in the `app.component.ts` . In ionic3 I used events to communicate between views, but that seems to be gone.

Comment: Personally, I'd extract your fooBar() method from your `MainView` component into a service. However, there does appear to be a way to call methods of components that are rendered inside of `<router-outlet>` from the outside parent component. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949476/how-to-call-router-outlet-child-component-method-from-parent-comonent

Comment: `fooBar` does some UI stuff in the current view, I should add...

Comment: In a way it's like a remote procedure call, but within the app. So I liked the events lib in ionic3 for this.

Comment: Sure, I get it. Personally I'd go about it a different way. I like to extract most methods into services that manipulate the state of the application held in observables. Then in your view components subscribe to those observables and you can "do UI stuff" based on the changes to your state.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ion-menu events for your purposes.

```
Name              Description
ionDidClose       Emitted when the menu is closed.
ionDidOpen        Emitted when the menu is open.
ionWillClose      Emitted when the menu is about to be closed.
ionWillOpen       Emitted when the menu is about to be opened.
```

like this.

```
<ion-menu (ionDidOpen)="foBar()" contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
```

It will trigger when open the side menu.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by writing my own event service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventsService {

    static subject = new Subject<any>();

    static sendMessage(text){
        EventsService.subject.next(text);
    }

    static getMessage(): Observable<any>{
        return EventsService.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

where one view `sendMessage` and the other waits to `getMessage` of a specific type.