# (How) can I call a parent component function from an NgbModal modal?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, parent-child

I'm using [NgbModal from @ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) to open modal windows from an Angular 6 application.  In one of these modals, I'd like a button click to close the modal and activate a function in the parent/launching component.  How can I do that?

I know that with ordinary child and parent components you can emit an event which is caught by the parent component (see [this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940984/angular2-call-function-of-parent-component#35941067)).  Is there something analogous I can do with my modal setup?  If not, what's the best approach here?

Current code in the parent (simplified):

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ModalComponent } from "...";
@Component ( {...} )
export class ParentComponent {
  ...
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}
  ...
  showModal(i:InputObject) {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalCompoenent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.i = i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The close button of the modal can call the [NgbActiveModal.close](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbActiveModal) method, with the modal result value as the parameter:

```
import { NgbActiveModal } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

export class ModalComponent {
  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }
}
```

```
<button type="button" (click)="activeModal.close('This is my answer')">Close</button>
```

---

In the parent component, you handle the [NgbModalRef.result](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModalRef) promise with the appropriate callbacks. The result value can be retrieved in the "success" callback, in which you can call any method of the parent component:

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent);
...
modalRef.result.then(
  (data: any) => {
    this.processData(data);
  },
  (reason: any) => { });
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j4rahu) for a demo.

Comment: Don't worry, I won't forget.  I think the best policy is to wait a day or two to see what other solutions might be presented.