# The proper way to call a function of a parent component in Angular 14

Tags: angular

I want to use events to handle this task. I tried the method explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940984/angular2-call-function-of-parent-component) but it did not work. I have the following code:

**childComponent.ts:**

```
//Getting parent method (Equipments)
@Output() addCompleted = new EventEmitter<string>();
processComplete() {
      this.addCompleted.emit('complete');
}
```

**parentComponent.ts:**

```
onUpdateGrid(e: any){
    alert("Works!")
  }
```

**parentComponent.html:**

```
<ejs-grid #Grid class="data-grid" (addCompleted)="onUpdateGrid($event)" . . .>
    . . . .
</ejs-grid>
```

The only thing I could not follow from that thread is `directives: [ ChildComponent ]` in `@Component` because it is deprecated.

When I run the code, the parent method does not run.

**Update:
Child component decorator:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-equipment',
  templateUrl: './add-equipment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-equipment.component.scss']
})
```

Comment: How/when is `processComplete` called?

Comment: @eol When is button is pressed.

Comment: Did you import it like this: `import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: @EliPorush Yes, There are no errors in the code.

Comment: Did you check that this function `processComplete` is called when you click the button?

Comment: @AlexWright is `<ejs-grid>` your child component selector?

Comment: @akotech yes, it is a Syncfusion component

Comment: @akotech the button has a submit type and is in the child component and by pressing it, some data are stored in the database. I want to refresh the parent component after submitting it. For this, I need to call a function in the parent component.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example e.g. on codepen?

Comment: @AlexWright could you pls edit the question and add the full child Component class code?

Comment: @AlexWright Sorry I should've been more specific. What I really wanted to see was the `@Component` decorator to see the selector.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase the question... You asked a very confusing question. While the ejs-grid is rendered by your "parent component", it is a third party component that you have no control of, so you don't need to add a new @Output to deal with inter-component communication. You need to [read the docs](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/grid/#events) for the ejs-grid and find something that you can use to react to whatever is happening in that component. What are you trying to achieve exactly? Refresh the grid after you added a new equipment?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu yes, I want to refresh the grid and view the newly added record.

Comment: OK, then you need to clear the following: Which component is rendering the ejs-grid? Is the `app-add-equipment` component rendering it, or yet another component? Add the template code with regards to ejs-grid (without omitting anything), in order for people to see what you pass in as dataSource and which events you handle. In short, after you add the new item, you need to insert it in your datasource somehow. Either by "surgically inserting it in there" or less elaborate and efficient, call your backend to get the updated list.

Comment: @AlexWright thanx for the edit. If your child component selector is `app-add-equipment` you can only listen to the `addCompleted` event on its tag, like `<app-add-equipment (addCompleted)="callbackToExec($event)">`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this matches your use case, but maybe you could use the actionBegin event of ejs-grid.

Here is a quick example:

**html:**

```
<ejs-grid ...
(actionBegin)="actionBegin($event)">
...
</ejs-grid>
```

**ts:**

```
actionBegin(args: any) :void {
    let gridInstance: any = (<any>document.getElementById('Normalgrid')).ej2_instances[0];
    console.log(args); // this is just to show the result in the console
    if (args.requestType === 'save') {
        if (gridInstance.pageSettings.currentPage !== 1 && gridInstance.editSettings.newRowPosition === 'Top') {
            args.index = (gridInstance.pageSettings.currentPage * gridInstance.pageSettings.pageSize) - gridInstance.pageSettings.pageSize;
        } else if (gridInstance.editSettings.newRowPosition === 'Bottom') {
            args.index = (gridInstance.pageSettings.currentPage * gridInstance.pageSettings.pageSize) - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample of console output:**

[image: Sample of console output]

You can find a full example here: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app.component.ts,app.component.html  (official example)
API documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/editing/in-line-editing/

Comment: I have used `actionBegin` for server-side pagination. Can I use another one?

Comment: No, but you can add other code in the handler. However, according to the documentation, paging is done via the load event; cf. https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/paging/

Comment: Mmm, the documentation seems not clear how to implement server paging. Maybe the load event isn't helpful for that case. I've found this example instead: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntgj93-raw8be?file=async-pipe.component.ts There they use the dataStateChange event.